# Creating and assigning different variables using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

So what I'm trying to do is the following:

I have 300+ CSVs in a certain folder. What I want to do is open each CSV and take only the first row of each.

What I wanted to do was the following:

```
import os

list_of_csvs = os.listdir() # puts all the names of the csv files into a list.
```

The above generates a list for me like `['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv']`.

This is great and all, but where I get stuck is the next step. I'll demonstrate this using pseudo-code:

```
import pandas as pd

for index,file in enumerate(list_of_csvs):
    df{index} = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Basically, I want my for loop to iterate over my `list_of_csvs` object, and read the first item to df1, 2nd to df2, etc. But upon trying to do this I just realized - *I have no idea how to change the variable being assigned when doing the assigning via an iteration*!!!

That's what prompts my question. I managed to find another way to get my original job done no problemo, but this issue of doing variable assignment over an interation is something I haven't been able to find clear answers on!

Comment: what will you do with the first few rows?

Comment: standard rule: if you have many elements then keep them on list. So don't try to create `df1`, `df2` but keep it on list or dictionary - `df[1]`, `df[2]` - it will be more useful

Comment: @Datanovice the first row just contains some personal info that's also present on all the other rows. We don't really need the first row per se, just any row at all from each of the 300 will do.

Comment: use a dict `csv_contents = { file: df }`

Comment: `list_of_csvs = os.listdir()` will give MORE than just a list of `*.csv` files.

Comment: @accdias Yep I go through another step where I filter the list using certain prefixes so I get only the CSVs I need, but for the sake of brevity I left that out.

Comment: OP if you continue to use `os` module check out `glob` you can use it in conjunction to parse directories for files much like below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If i understand your requirement correctly, we can do this quite simply, lets use Pathlib instead of `os` which was added in python 3.4+

```
from pathlib import Path
csvs = Path.cwd().glob('*.csv') # creates a generator expression.
#change Path(your_path) with Path.cwd() if script is in dif location

dfs = {} # lets hold the csv's in this dictionary

for file in csvs:
   dfs[file.stem] = pd.read_csv(file,nrows=3) # change nrows [number of rows] to your spec.

#or with a dict comprhension
dfs = {file.stem : pd.read_csv(file) for file in Path('location\of\your\files').glob('*.csv')}
```

this will return a dictionary of dataframes with the key being the csv file name `.stem` adds this without the extension name.

much like

```
{
'csv_1' : dataframe,
'csv_2' : dataframe
}
```

if you want to concat these then do

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

the index will be the csv file name.