# Creating a function to open a file while naming it

Tags: python, pandas, function, csv

I am trying to create a function to open several  files from a local directory and to name it.
I have tried the following (which already works outside of the function):

```
def read_csv_for_tsv_files(table_name):
{table_name}_scn_csv = pd.read_csv(fr'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\{table_name}.csv', sep=';',
                                      error_bad_lines=False)
```

However, I am getting an invalid syntax error. Does anybody have advice?

The line does work like this:

```
table_name_scn_csv = 
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\table_name_scn.csv',sep=';', 
error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Can you give more detail about what, specifically, works outside of the function? Assigning to a variable without the `{}`?

Comment: yes, adjusted the question..

Comment: What is `{table_name}_scn_csv` meant to be ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Creating names dynamically is not good idea, check http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html

Comment: not related to your error - but I've posted a solution for this a while back using pandas and pathlib see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823218/creating-and-assigning-different-variables-using-a-for-loop/59823370#59823370)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to assign to a dynamically named variable based on the table name. While it is possible to do this using e.g. [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), it is probably not a good idea.

If you want to store the loaded files so that they are accessible by name, the easiest way is probably to use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
tables = {}

def load_csv(table_name):
    tables[table_name] = pd.read_csv(...)
```

Then you can access each table using the `[]` operator on the dict:

```
load_csv("table_1")
load_csv("table_2")

# ...

table_to_use = tables["table_2"]
# do something with table 2...
```

Comment: In what way does this address the question, which is about a syntax error ?

Comment: The syntax error is caused by trying to dynamically name a variable using some f-string-like syntax, presumably in order to reference each table by its name. This answer is what OP should do instead.

Comment: @YvesDaoust edited for clarity